# jQuery qTip2 not displaying or linking properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, qtip2

I'm using jQuery qTip2 for tooltips in my Rails app. I want the tooltip to display a link, but I can't get that (or the tooltip itself) to show properly.

Here's my application.js qTip jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.article span[alt]').qtip({
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'bottom center'
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true
        },
        style: {
            width: 200
        }
    });
});
```

My html.erb to show the tooltip:

```
<li class="article"><span alt=<%= link_to article.name, article_path %>>
    <%= article.body %>
</span></li>
```

And my header:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.qtip.css?1316753274" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.qtip.min.css?1316753274" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1316133561" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1316962938" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.qtip.js?1316753274" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.qtip.min.js?1316753274" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**EDIT -** Here's the HTML that shows:

```
<li class="article"><span alt=<a href="/articles/2">Article Name</a>>
Testing
</span></li>
```

The goal is that hovering over testing shows the tooltip link "Article Name", which takes you to the article.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Please show the HTML code as seen by the browser instead of your template.

Comment: Describe what _"can't get that to show properly"_ means.  You also included all the qTip files twice... see my answer below.

Comment: Added the HTML code as seen by browser and an explanation of what the intended behavior is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the qTip2 JavaScript twice...

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.qtip.js?1316753274" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.qtip.min.js?1316753274" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**You only need one instance of qTip2; pick one to keep and remove the other one.**

You are also including the qTip2 CSS file twice but, if identical, this would not cause a major problem... it's just wasteful and redundant.  Remove one...

```
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.qtip.css?1316753274" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.qtip.min.css?1316753274" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**EDIT:**

This is not even close to being valid HTML...

```
<span alt=<a href="/articles/2">Article Name</a>>Testing</span>
```

- The `alt` attribute need to be followed by text within quotation marks.  `alt="my alternate text"`
- You cannot use the `alt` tag without the quotation marks and AFAIK, you cannot put HTML within the `alt` attribute.

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute

This might work...

```
<span alt="&lt;a href='\/articles\/2'&gt;Article Name&lt;\/a&gt;">Testing</span>
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks, I've removed one set of .js and .css files.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? Or would any solution not be valid HTML?

Comment: I'm assuming I'll have to add this as a new question but is there a way to include erb in my js file? I know I can include a link in my qTip but need to access the database to provide the link dynamically.

Comment: @tvalent2, I make a suggestion at the end of my answer... try that or something similar.  Your other follow-up should probably be posted as a whole new question.

Comment: I added another question as follow-up but you helped a great deal! Here's the new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548956/rails-dynamic-content-in-jquery-qtip2