# Rails 3.2.1 ruby 1.9.3 qtip2 trying to get dynamic content with ajax and getting a stack overflow

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I've found several questions relating to the problem, but despite copying the solution I can't get it to work. For example [Rails dynamic content in jQuery qTip2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548956/rails-dynamic-content-in-jquery-qtip2).

The processing gets to the controller to produce the content but it gets into a loop.

```
$('td.config_info_tip').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Loading',
        ajax: {
            url: 'config',
            data:   {
                "id": $(this).attr("id")
            },
            method: 'get'
        }
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    }
});
```

In the controller

```
def config
  id = params[:id]
  @device = Device.find_by_id(id)
  @devicecategory = DeviceCategory.find_by_id(@device.device_category_id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render layout: false}
  end
end
```

As it goes through the render, it goes back into the config function, looping until it overflows and I get

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

I have another qtip doing a similar thing that works fine - the differences are I can see is that I'm passing in data on the one that doesn't work. The other subtlety is that the page with the tip that doesn't work is itself rendered with jquery, and so the js code for the tip is in on the page, whilst the one that does work is in a  $(document).ready function. I would love to understand where this is going wrong.

I've tried taking out the respond_to and just having

```
render layout: false
```

This one works:

```
 $('img#priceinfo').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Loading',
        ajax: {
            url: 'pricing',
            type: 'GET'
        }
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    }
  });
```

And the controller

```
def current
  @d = Date.today
   # ought to check that we have prices defined
  @price = Price.where("effective_from < ?", @d).order("effective_from desc").first
  render layout: false

end
```

Anyone any ideas - its stumped me for hours now?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know why, but changing the name of the method in the controller from config to device_config sorted the problem.

Comment: That is because it is a [reserved word](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords).